# cannot resolve symbol PendingIntent

Tags: android

I am trying to create a pending inteent for NotificationManager.
However I am getting below error 
"cannot resolve symbol PendingIntent"

My code is this

```
        Intent mdi = new Intent(this, MonthlyDetailsActivity.class);
        mdi.putExtra("month", Integer.parseInt(monthsIdVector.get(position)));
        mdi.putExtra("year", Integer.parseInt(YearVector.get(position)));
        PendingIntent viewPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Check : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
```

in your `Activity`

For more information go to [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)

Comment: This and syncing Gradle did not solve it for me. I also changed minSDK to be 16 when it was 15, but that shouldn't affect the existence of the class, I'd think.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import **android.app.PendingIntent** class in your code. If you are using Eclipse IDE then just use **Ctrl+Shift+O** shortcut to manage all imports.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, somehow my Android studio didnt import it automatically ... 
I found a solution for that.

Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Auto Import -> Java

make the following changes:

```
change Insert imports on paste value to All from Drop Down menu
Add unambigious imports on the fly option as checked
```

Now, click on APPLY and OK to save changes.

This will auto import all the classes when you PASTE any code in editor.